# Php - echoing an html textbox, setting the textbox's value to a variable: returns only up to the first space of the string

Tags: php

So within my php code: I'm trying to auto generate and populate a form that will edit a database.

```
$aName = "Wayne Gretzky";
echo "<form>";
echo "<input type='text' value=".$aName.">";
echo "<input type='Submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

But when the code executes it shows a textbox with the value of "Wayne" rather than "Wayne Gretzky"

Because i want the form to be auto generated, so it can adapt to whatever data I may pull form the database; How do i call the variable or the result of a query so that the full string will be displayed in the textbox?

Comment: try `"<input type='text' value='".$aName."'>";`

Comment: @Blkc Breaks when `$aName = "I'm me";`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol oh I miss the `edit a database` part in the question, a good example to start with will be https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotes on the value attribute as well, otherwise the browser does it for you and then you get what you got.

```
echo "<input type='text' value='" . $aName . "'>";
```

Comment: XSS ahoy, you might want to do something about the injection vulnerability when `$aName` contains an apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

You are going wrong with the quotes. 
If you are using double quotes outside, use single quotes inside for the html tags.

The correct code is

```
<?php
$aName = "Wayne Gretzky";
echo "<form>";
echo "<input type='text' value='$aName'>";
echo "<input type='Submit'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```